# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) on project automation: There are test failures

Tags: maven, testng, pom.xml

Not able to run a single test using: 
    mvn -Dtest=SettingsTest#test* test

I have followed the steps mentioned here: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

It throws an error:

> 

```html
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.225 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-14T11:00:10-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) on project automation: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/iOS-automation/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

My pom.xml :

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.abc</groupId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>automation</name>
  <description>iOS app automation</description>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
              <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
                      <suiteXmlFile>parth.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                  </suiteXmlFiles>
     </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.5.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <source>1.8</source>
                  <target>1.8</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       <version>3.8.1</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.47.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   <version>6.8</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.googlejavaformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-java-format</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
 </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
</project>
```

all other commands like: mvn clean install, mvn clean compile works fine.

Is there something wrong in my pom.xml or something wrong with the setup?

Comment: Show the complete error message.

Comment: @JFMeier please have a look now. I have added the complete error message.

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the error message?

Comment: @JFMeier yes, i did. But theres nothing which provides more details. As i mentioned in the post "mvn clean install" "mvn compile" works fine without any reason. its the issue while running single test case.

Comment: So you went through the test reports?

Comment: yes, i went through the reports it not showing anything

Comment: @ParthParikh I met the same error. Did you find a solution pls?

Answer (score 0):

R u using any plugin in your project? As mentioned in following article this exception is not coming from maven, it is generating from plugins
https://cwiki.apache.org//confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException